# Text positioning when using -webkit-transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to make a bar with text and image appear when clicking a button (as if it were a notification), this bar will grow until reaching the maximum size and revealing the content, however while the animation happens the text is re-positioning , I would like it to be stopped in its position and only the bar would move.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style> 
      .notification {
          width: 0px;
          height: 100px;
          background: whitesmoke;
          display: flex;

          overflow: hidden;

          -webkit-transition: width 2s;
          transition: width 2s;
      }

      .show {
          width: 450px;
      }
 
      .avatar img {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 20px;
      }

      .text {
        margin: 5px 20px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="notification">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1147/PNG/512/1486486303-alert-bell-notification-education-christmas-bell-church-bell-ring_81235.png">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p><strong>Call Notification</strong></p>
        <p>Receive a notification by a determinate person - <strong>PERSON NAME</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <button>Notify</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      let notification = document.querySelector('.notification');

      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
        notification.classList.add('show');
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried adding the white-space: nowrap property.

```
.text {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 5px 20px;
      }
```

It even works the way I wanted it to, but if the text is too large (larger than the width of the bar) it will be hidden by the overflow: hidden property.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style> 
      .notification {
          width: 0px;
          height: 100px;
          background: whitesmoke;
          display: flex;

          overflow: hidden;

          -webkit-transition: width 2s;
          transition: width 2s;
      }

      .show {
          width: 450px;
      }
 
      .avatar img {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        margin: 20px;
      }

      .text {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 5px 20px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="notification">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1147/PNG/512/1486486303-alert-bell-notification-education-christmas-bell-church-bell-ring_81235.png">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p><strong>Call Notification</strong></p>
        <p>Receive a notification by a determinate person - <strong>PERSON NAME</strong></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>

    <button>Notify</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      let notification = document.querySelector('.notification');

      document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
        notification.classList.add('show');
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the text fixed width and disable the shrink effect on it in order to keep that fixed width thus the text won't move and you simply show it:

```js
let notification = document.querySelector('.notification');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  notification.classList.add('show');
});
```

```css
.notification {
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  background: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.show {
  width: 450px;
}

.avatar img {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.text {
  margin: 5px 20px;
  width:calc(450px - 70px - 2*20px); /*total width - image width - margin of image*/
  flex-shrink:0; /* avoid the width of the element to be reduced by the shrink effect*/
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">
  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1147/PNG/512/1486486303-alert-bell-notification-education-christmas-bell-church-bell-ring_81235.png">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p><strong>Call Notification</strong></p>
    <p>Receive a notification by a determinate person - <strong>PERSON NAME</strong></p>
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<button>Notify</button>
```